# Getting the Cities belonging to the selected Country for the initial request

Tags: python, django

I need to return only the Cities belonging on the current selected Country.

Any idea how I can do this?

I understand I need to use JavaScript to update the list but how can I do that for the initial request, given I am loading the whole field in my view using: {{ profile_form.city }}

City model has a foreign key for Country.

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this app, sure it will help you a lot, and can save you a lot of time  https://github.com/dpnova/django-simple-cities.